# Why Isn't the Result Stored in my Variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store the result of a user input from a text input element in a variable, it appears that the input is assigned briefly but then disappears. I have no idea why the result doesn't stay?

```
var searchInput;

function inputResult() {
    searchInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    alert(searchInput);
};
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: when are you calling inputResult() ? Can we see your html too?

Comment: Hi,

I am calling the function with:

<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="search" id="futSearch" onclick="inputResult()">Search</button>

Comment: When I console.log(searchInput); it is undefined. I think it should have the result of the input?

Comment: yes it should, but we need to see more html/js, could you reproduce the problem in a snippet? or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, I have copied it all over to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/darrylmorley/gaL92p67/5/

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working fine.

```js
var searchInput;

function inputResult() {
  searchInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  alert(searchInput);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<button onclick="inputResult()">Check value</button>
```